# How do I add a custom login and logout page in my Tableau Server on-prem?

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop, bi-tool

I am having the scenario for tableau server as follows:

1. I want to have a custom login/logout page. Logging to my custom page, I want to use either trusted auth or SSO and bypass the tableau server login screen. This step theoretically seems possible.
2. How can I prevent logout or session timeout from redirecting to the default tableau login page but instead redirect to my custom logout page? Also, how can I prevent direct access to the tableau server URL i.e. if block someone who visits the tableau server URL directly without going through my web app,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is "officially" possible to make a custom login page as you described but maybe you can start with some tutorial that shows how to hack the official login page `C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\9.0\vizportalclient\public\<language>` and create a custom HTML/JS script on it.

Usually, tutorials are about adding background, color, ... and not sophisticated functions so you probably have to create all from zero and there are a lot of chances to corrupt the file.
One of the best tutorial IMHO is [this one](https://tableaulove.tumblr.com/post/114891230420/can-i-still-hack-the-login-screen-in-tableau).

[image]

Comment: Got it. But I want a more custom UI page. Rather than tweaking tableau code which is mostly going to break something, we can use Trusted Auth/SSO to bypass the login page from my webpage. Only concern is around the case when somebody logs out where nginx can again be configured to redirect to the login page.